# Expression for people who are similar

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word or expression for people who share similar interests? Can the word "alike" be used in this case?

Comment: Like i said, similar in interests , not appearance. Im searching for a word, but expressions also helps.

Comment: "share similar interests"?

Answer (score 7):

1. Birds of a feather
2. Kindred spirits
3. Soul sisters/brothers(?)

Comment: Perhaps if you could define the meanings of these idioms, and supply links the user would be better informed. It's obvious that the OP is not a native speaker (please see previous edit history).

Answer (score 7):

I can't really help much without more context but you're probably looking for *like-minded*, [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like-minded) by the online Merriam-Webster as

> having a like disposition or purpose :  of the same mind or habit of thought

For example:

> She enjoyed the club because she could meet like-minded people.

Answer (score 0):

homogeneous
adjective uk   /ˌhɒm.əˈdʒiː.ni.əs/ /ˌhəʊ.mə-/ us    /ˌhoʊ.moʊˈdʒiː-/
› consisting of parts or people that are similar to each other or are of the same type: a homogeneous group/society The population of the village has remained remarkably homogeneous.
Compare
(Definition of homogeneous from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary © Cambridge University Press)